# What are the consequences of having a relative long TimeOut connection?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, connection

I'm programming a socket with Java and I'm wondering if are there consequences of setting a long "TimeOut" connection? Let's say more than 10 min.

Thank you for the clarification

Comment: Setting a long timeout will literally just make the socket wait more time before it stops waiting for a server response. Is this all you wanted to know, or were you looking for secondary consequences like the bandwidth load on the client or something (because AFAIK there aren't any)?

Answer (score 1):

Despite what it says in the Javadoc, you can't increase the connect timeout beyond the platform default of about 60 seconds, and zero does not mean infinity: it means the platform timeout.